# Need help to plan database interaction between microservices using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, microservices

We are recently planning to migrate from Monolithic architecture to Microservices and our application currently has 4 parts i.e. Host, Users, Bookings and Admin. Currently we have everything in one Backend project that runs on NodeJs and all connected with one MongoDB database.

But, We are thinking to convert this setup into 4 microservices (Host, Users, Bookings and Admin) with each service having its own dedicated MongoDb database (database per service). Furthermore, Amazon SQS/SNS will be used as message broker for this setup and NGINX as api gateway.

Our team is completely new to the Microservices concept, and our biggest hurdle right now is to figure out how we can setup the database transaction as mentioned in the scenario below. Our previous work will now be divided into 4 different databases:

**(A) Host database properties collection:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffec1ae22f2bb36523780d6"),
    
    "userData" : {
        /* how to load required data from user service here? */
    },
    
    "country" : {
        "tax" : NumberInt(16),
        "_id" : "5f73498bd375330b80df7cc9",
        "id" : NumberInt(82),
        "name" : "Germany",
        "sortname" : "DE"
    },
    "city" : {
        "isFeatured" : true,
        "_id" : "5f73659429716f20b5643933",
        "cityName" : "Berlin"
    },
    "isFeaturedProperty" : false,
    "coHostId" : [

    ],
    "autoAcceptUpcomingBooking" : true,
    "status" : "archive",
    "stepCounter" : NumberInt(1),
    "totalBookingsCount" : NumberInt(0),
    "averageDuration" : NumberInt(0),
    "ongoingBookingCount" : NumberInt(0),
    "upComingBookingCount" : NumberInt(0),
    "totalCapacity" : NumberInt(33),
    "unitsBooked" : NumberInt(0),
    "termsAndCond" : "",
    "propertyType" : NumberInt(1),
    "name" : "Wonder – Women’s Coworking",
    "addressPrimary" : "Prenzlauer Allee",
    "state" : {
        "_id" : "5f734acfd375330b80df82b4",
        "id" : NumberInt(3010),
        "name" : "Berlin"
    },
    "zipCode" : "10115",
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            7.0108,
            51.9553
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "description" : "my description that can be more than 255 characters long",
    "amenities" : [
        {
            "status" : "active",
            "isFeatured" : NumberInt(0),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ffec0b522f2bb3652378060"),
            "name" : "pharma and healthcare",
            "iconImage" : "https://myimageurl.com",
            "amenityId" : ObjectId("5f43bf95fcdd794963c06caf"),
            "type" : " Business Industries"
        },
        {
            ...
                // 50 more such amenities objects
            ...
        }
    ],
    "totalUnits" : NumberInt(65),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5f743e01bcac04616ace8d8a"),
    "address" : "Prenzlauer Allee",
}
```

**(B) Bookings Database collection:**

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6026ca0fff49757776612096"),
        "userData" : {
    
            /* how to load required data from user service here? */
        
        },
        
        "adminData" : {
    
            /* how to load data from admin service here? */
        
        }

        "propertyData" : {
            "status" : "active",
            "propertyId" : ObjectId("5ffec1ae22f2bb36523780d6"),
            
            /* how to load some more data from Host properties 
            /* table in Host database above in here? */
            
            "hostEmail" : "support@bookings.com",
            "hostImage" : "http://image.com/6.jpeg",
            "hostName" : "Foo bar"
        },

        "category" : {
            "options" : [
                "Hot Coffee"
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f75c18c50aad61e8e604b64"),
            "name" : "cafe room",
            "colorCode" : "#1ebc78",
            "description" : null,
            "iconImage" : null
        },
        "bookingStatus" : NumberInt(2),
        "userBookingStatus" : NumberInt(0),
        "bookingMode" : NumberInt(1),
        "timing" : "Full Day",
        "coworkerCount" : NumberInt(0),
        "quantity" : NumberInt(1),
        "spaceId" : ObjectId("6026c894ff49757776612080"),
        "fromDate" : ISODate("2021-02-14T02:30:00.000+0000"),
        "toDate" : ISODate("2021-02-14T17:30:00.000+0000"),
        "occupancy" : NumberInt(10),
        "bookingId" : "DSK6204351",
        "hostId" : ObjectId("5f73b086bcac04616ace8b18")
    }
```

**User Database and Admin database will also follow the same structure as above with different schema**

***What I want:***

What would be the best practice to get the data from Admin, User and the Host database and fill up the commented placeholder in the Bookings database (fig. B)?

Similarly, what would be the best practice to get the data from user database and fill up in the userData section of Host db's property collection? the place where I've added comments (fig. A).

***What I Tried***

Tried reading a lot about microservices for 2-3 days straight, I also tried thinking of a strategy using saga microservices pattern where we publish the changes to message broker (Amazon sqs) as soon as we create user, block user on the admin side, or create a new property on the host side, and then alert the bookings and host services about any updates that take place.

But I feel this way there will be too much data duplication in all databases that will be hard to maintain as we grow.

Comment: May I ask why you're transitioning from the monolith to microservices?

Comment: @LeviRamsey because the application on the backend side has become one big project with code that is not following any architecture or good coding standards, we are finding it very difficult to maintain and extend further. Also, the database is currently not optimised as some queries are taking longer than expected to return with a response. This code base was delivered to us by third parties and we worked to fix it for one whole year before deciding to migrate to Microservices. Do you think that there is no need for it?